# Making AdHoc for iphone

Tags: iphone, provisioning, adhoc

I don't have apple developer account and i have  made an app which i want to run on my device.

is there any other option to do this..?

Alternatively---i have an app which  has that certificate can i use that to make an adhoc?

NOTE- i  am not sending my app to appstore....it is for self purpose only

please also provide a link for an adhoc tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all necessary information are here: [Deploying iPhone Apps to Real Devices](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

and here: [Beta testing on iphone](http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/) (a little bit older)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you need to have a paid ($99) Apple Developers Licence to deploy an application onto any device (either Local Device, via Adhoc or through the AppStore).

Being a 'Registered Only' developer you only have access to the SDK tools and Documentation.  The SDK tools include the Simulator that you can use for testing ... as I'm sure you are already aware of, considering you have developed an app.

Only other alternative I can think of is to send your code to a developer with the licence and let him/her install it onto their device.  My opinion, that's not really gonna help you in the long run.
My advice is to get an individual Developers Licence and try the programme for 12 Months, you will probably find that you will cover your costs with an app or two.

Good Luck